# Working with Secure implementation of web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I am new to Web-Api, Cloud etc. I have some requirements with my project but as lots of resources are available over internet, I am not able to decide which way should i go.

**Requirements:**

- The user should identify themselves with an authority (i.e facebook/google etc)
- The users `nameidentifier` should be passed to our Web-API and stored in a database
- Get the token/key that was given to us when the user authenticated themselves
- Send the token in the header of every api-request and verify the users identity
- It should run on a mobile client application (Windows phone, Android, iOS).

**Question:**

1) What is the simplest way to identify a client when using an external authority and then authorise the client when they call our web-api?

2) Is it possible to configure AD to use an external identity provider (i.e facebook, google) or can this only be done using ACS?

3) The only think needed is the `nameidentifer` (no name or email address, etc).

**Relevant Links**

- Their [Asp.Net Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx)
- [Individual Accounts With WebApi-2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services)
- And there is something about [Active Directory](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/11/07/provisioning-a-directory-tenant-as-an-identity-provider-in-an-acs-namespace/), all are claiming which i need but which one i should go for ? What are pro and cons ?

Comment: Try investigating using ASP.NET Identity: http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: @martin_costello i got this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463788.aspx what do u think about it?

Comment: This functionality is built into ASP.NET Web. When you create your project, choose change authentication and select the option for individual user accounts. It allows you to set up Facebook, Google, and Microsoft authentication out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to define the Authorize attribute through the suggestions made by the following book: http://www.apress.com/9781430261759

You can download the source code from the above link, and chapter 8 or 9 can give you the solution that you are looking for!